# Why σελήνη instead of ἑλήνη?

Tags: etymology, greek, phonology

The Greek word for the moon is σελήνη *selēnē*, σελᾱνᾱ *selānā*, or σελάννᾱ *selánnā*, depending on dialect. All seem to come transparently from the same root as σέλας *sélas*, "shine".

But since these both appear to be native words (hence the varying across dialects), why do they show initial /s/? I was taught that initial /s/ before a vowel became /h/ in early Greek, hence cognates *sept-* versus *hept-*, *semi-* versus *hemi-*, and so on.

Comment: @AlexB. The problem is that this "s" is not mobile. It is always there.

Comment: Mea culpa, not Beekes'! Same link, [Pre-Greek Loanwords in Greek](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/greek): "15. **A σ occurs both word‑initially and between vowels, where it has disappeared in most inherited words.** Initial: σάρυττα, σαγύριον, σάναπτιν, σάνδαλον, σαρρυφθεῖν, σεκούα, σιβύνη, σίγυμνον. Intervocalic: ἀγασυλλίς, ἄγχουσα (ἔγχ‑), αἴθουσ(σ)α, αἱμασιά, αἴσακος, ἄλεισον, δρόσος. After resonant: ἄλσος, βάλσαμον, γελσόν, γένσιμος, μάρσιππος (-υππος)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual explanation (e.g. in Beekes) is that selēnē is a Greek formation from selas “light”: *selas-nā > selēnē, with the same suffix (and the same semantics) as in Latin *luk-nā > lūna. For selas there is no adequate etymology and it may well be non Indo-European (borrowing or pre-Greek substrate).

Answer (score 8):

fdb already wrote that there is no adequate Indo-European etymology and most likely it is a loan from the Pre-Greek substratum. That being said, another etymology has been in circulation for many decades - its connection to the word 'sun' in PIE (i.e. *séh<sub>2</sub>u̯el-; see below). This is what Michel Lejeune wrote in his ["Phonétique historique du mycénien et du grec ancien"](http://www.klincksieck.com/livre/?GCOI=22520100333210) (1972/2017, p. 135):

> "L'altération de *sw ancien est donc établie par une série d'exemples sûrs. Cependant, on a supposé que, dans quelques racines, le grec aurait conservé le groupe ancien *sw- (comme il aurait, dans quelques racines, conservé le groupe *sm-, §113); aux approches de l'époque historique, ϝ se serait amuï dans ce groupe initial, ainsi réduit a σ: par example dans σέλας "éclat" qu'on rapproche de skr. svargáḥ "ciel" [...]. Mais, de ces rapprochements possibles, aucun ne s'impose; ces termes, comme la plupart des mots grecs commençant par σ- devant voyelle, demeurent obscurs. Emprunts?"

Basically, it says that it is possible that in some words *sw might have been preserved (i.e. we end up with PIE *sw > Greek s), we could posit a connection between Greek σέλας and Sanskrit svargáḥ 'heaven'; however, because the origin of the Greek words that start with σ- followed by a vowel remains obscure and the connections are not particularly convincing, Lejeune concludes by saying that such words are probably loans ('emprunts').

cf. Sihler (1995) "the usual etymon, PIE *swelH- 'gleam', is well-attested, but **G σ- < *sw is hard to accept**" (p. 216; emphasis mine - A.B.).

That being said, different Indo-European cognates have been suggested - the following is mentioned in [NIL](https://www.winter-verlag.de/de/detail/978-3-8253-5359-9/Wodtko_ua_Hg_Nomina_im_Indogerm_Lexikon/) under PIE *séh<sub>2</sub>u̯el- 'sun':

- Avestan x<sup>v</sup>arənah- 'glory, splendour' (Bader 1995, Janda
  2004);
- Vedic (Sanskrit) sauvá- 'belonging to the Sun' (Darms 1978),

cf. "Anschluß von gr. σέλας n. 'Licht, Glanz' (Il.+) und/oder aav. jav. x<sup>v</sup>arənah- n. ~ 'Ruhmesglanz' an das Word für 'Sonne' wurde oft erwogen" (NIL, p. 611, note 16).

However, fdb agrees with Silher that:

> Greek s < sw is without parallel. Besides, there is the semantic difficulty of the proposed shift of meaning from “sun” to “moon”. The Greek descendant of *swel-nā seems to be εἵλη “warmth of the sun”. The same root (IE *swel-) is also the source of Avestan xvarənah- according to Almut Hintze, Der Zamyād Yašt, pp. 28-33 (with detailed discussion of other proposals).

Comment: This seems interesting, but unfortunately I don't speak French.

Comment: @Draconis Basically, it says that it is possible that in some words *sw might have been preserved (i.e. we end up with PIE *sw > Greek s), we could posit a connection between Greek σέλας and Sanskrit svargáḥ 'heaven'; however, because the origin of the Greek words that start with σ- followed by a vowel remains obscure and the connections are not particularly convincing, Lejeune concludes by saying that such words are probably loans ('emprunts').

Comment: Interesting! Mind adding that to the answer?

Comment: I agree with Sihler that Greek s < sw is without parallel. Besides, there is the semantic difficulty of the proposed shift of meaning from “sun” to “moon”. The Greek descendant of *swel-nā seems to be εἵλη “warmth of the sun”. The same root (IE *swel-) is also the source of Avestan xvarənah- according to Almut Hintze, Der Zamyād Yašt, pp. 28-33 (with detailed discussion of other proposals).

Comment: @fdb and Alex B. That's some excellent information which I wasn't previously aware of! Mind adding all of that into the answer? (I'm not sure of the etiquette in editing answers to your own question.)

Comment: @Draconis feel free to add or modify anything I write as you deem necessary, it's fine with me

Comment: @Draconis Other words beginning with sw- in PIE end up as h- in Greek, e.g. *swād- "sweet" to Greek ἡδύς (and the epichoric variants don't include s- anywhere). I wonder if there are exceptions to that, though.

Answer (score 6):

There are AFAIK no outer relations for the Greek words  σέλας sélas and σελήνη selēnē attested.

This leaves two possibilities:

- The words are early loans into Proto-Hellenic from an unknown source language
- The words can still be inherited from Proto-Indogermanic (and just died out in the other branches) and the proto-word started in a more complicated consonant cluster like /ks/. Under such circumstances, an initial /s/ in Greek can be obtained. An example for this is the prefix συν- that is also found as old Att. ξύν-.

Comment: Good answer! Are there other examples of initial #sV coming from each of these methods?

Comment: Of ξύν, Wiktionary says "-υ- < *-o- is expected, but -σ- < *-s- and -σ- < *-ξ- are not". I don't have enough knowledge of Proto-Greek to say, but is *ks- > *s- a regular sound change?

Comment: @Draconis *ks- > s- does not seem to be regular; there are a couple of other sporadic cases (ξίρις~σίρις, ξύλον~σύλον) but usually PIE *ks- seems to remain unchanged. That said, there aren't that many words in ξ- with secure etymologies.