# Where does -na come from?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

In [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6090/406), fdb suggested that Greek *selēnē* < *selannā* < **selas-nā* and Latin *lūna* < *losnā* < **lowks-nā* share a suffix.

What is this noun-forming *-nā*, and is it the same one that's seen in e.g. *ruina*? How long did it remain productive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that *lowks-nā is originally a feminine (hence -ā) adjective meaning “shining”. The suffix *no commonly forms adjectives, e.g. dignus, magnus, plenus etc. It is the exact equivalent of Avestan raoxšna- “bright”.

Comment: Interesting! Is this at all related to *ruina* from *ruō*? And did it remain productive post-PIE at all?

Comment: @Draconis. The suffix *-īno- forms adjectives like caninus, or nouns like ruina, regina and many others. I am not sure how long it remained productive.

Comment: I would imagine it remained productive throughout Classical Latin; e.g *constantinus* from *constans* is a post-classical derivation.

Comment: @cmw good point